# POEdit - Parser for ASP.NET (.cshtml) files

Tags: razor, localization, orchardcms, poedit

I am developing an Orchard module and installed POEdit for managing the localization (.po) files. Is it possible to configure POEdit for .cshtml files? In the settings there is no parser for *.cshtml files, so I added it at the "C#" language. This is not working well.

If I have a C# block in my cshtml code, POEdit recognizes the translation item:

```
if (...)
{
    @T("test translation")
}
```

If I have a HTML block, it does not recognize the translation item:

```
<div title="@T("test translation inside html code")"></div>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Piotr Szmyd for your help. With the Orchard module [Translation Manager](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/creating-and-maintaining-orchard-translations)
I can update my .po files. But I had initial problems:

- Update .po files with one click
- Open .po files in POEdit (the extracted files from Translation Manager are not marked as UTF-8)

The solution is a little VBS script, that maybe help some of you with the same problem. Just save this to updateHelper.vbs (Don't forget to set the configuration values):

```
' ####################
' Configuration
Const OrchardPath       = ""      ' Path to Orchard
Const Modules           = ""      ' e.g. Orchard.Blogs,Orchard.Pages
Const DefaultCulture    = "en-us" ' default language
' ####################

OrchardWeb = OrchardPath & "\src\Orchard.Web"
OrchardBin = OrchardWeb & "\bin\"

WScript.Echo "Extracting T-strings from module..."
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run OrchardBin & "\Orchard extract default translation /Output:" & OrchardWeb & " /Extensions:" & Modules, 0, true

WScript.Echo "Extracting archive..."
ZipFile = OrchardWeb & "\Orchard." & DefaultCulture & ".po.zip"
ExtractTo = OrchardWeb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If NOT fso.FolderExists(ExtractTo) Then
   fso.CreateFolder(ExtractTo)
End If
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).items
objShell.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip)

WScript.Echo "Deleting archive..."
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists(ZipFile) Then
    filesys.DeleteFile ZipFile
End If

For Each orchardModule in Split(Modules, ",")
    WScript.Echo "Preparing files for module """ & orchardModule & """:"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set orchardModuleLanguages = objFSO.GetFolder(OrchardWeb & "\Modules\" & orchardModule & "\App_Data\Localization").Subfolders
    For Each orchardModuleLanguage in orchardModuleLanguages
        If NOT StrComp(orchardModuleLanguage.Name, DefaultCulture, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            WScript.Echo "Synchronizing to """ & orchardModuleLanguage.Name & """..."
            Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            objShell.Run OrchardBin & "\Orchard sync translation /Input:" & OrchardWeb & " /Culture:" & orchardModuleLanguage.Name, 0, true
        End If

        WScript.Echo "Preparing """ & orchardModuleLanguage.Name & """ for POEdit..."
        TranslationFile = OrchardWeb & "\Modules\" & orchardModule & "\App_Data\Localization\" & orchardModuleLanguage.Name & "\orchard.module.po"
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TranslationFile, 1) ' Reading
        strContents = objFile.ReadAll
        objFile.Close
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TranslationFile, 2) ' Writing
        objFile.WriteLine "msgid """""
        objFile.WriteLine "msgstr """""
        objFile.WriteLine """Language: " & orchardModuleLanguage.Name & "\n"""
        objFile.WriteLine """MIME-Version: 1.0\n"""
        objFile.WriteLine """Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"""
        objFile.WriteLine """Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"""
        objFile.WriteLine """X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"""
        objFile.WriteLine vbCrLf & strContents
        objFile.Close
    Next
Next

WScript.Echo "Process completed!"
```

Now create a .bat file with the following content, to get the progress output in the command shell:

```
@echo off
cscript updateHelper.vbs
pause
```

The script is executing the following commands:

1. Extracting all T-strings from the default language from special modules (Translation Manager)
2. Unzip the extracted archive to your module folder and overwrite the default language .po file
3. Deleting archive
4. Synchronizing to all other .po files, that are currently in your modules localization folder
5. Setting header data to all .po files, so they are prepared for POEdit (as UTF-8)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and most commonly used way to localize Orchard is to:

1. Generate *.po* files, using [Translation Manager](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/creating-and-maintaining-orchard-translations)
2. Use POEdit, or other means to fill the generated files with proper translations

The Translation Manager tool scans all code files (including *.cshtml* ones) for `T(...)` calls and generates proper .po files. It also includes commands to update/sync existing translations after code changes, making it a really useful tool.

Comment: Thanks for that! This is really helpful! But its hard to do a step by step translation, because I always have to extract and sync again. In POEdit I just would have to click the "refreh" button.

Another disadvantage: If I have an existing german UTF-8 translation und run 'sync', it overwrites the UFT-8 formatting and my german translation is useless. And the 'extract' command extracts multiple entries (i.e. I have a T-string in 2 files with the same name), but maybe this is the normal behaviour?

Comment: Having the same string appear multiple times is ok and desired, as the same text may mean slightly different things in different contexts. And this UTF-8 problem sounds like a bug - please file an issue here: https://vandelay.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic.

Comment: I just saw that its no bug. The translation file is properly saved as UTF-8 after 'sync translate'. But when I open it in POEdit, it does not recognize it as UTF-8 and mess some words up.

Comment: Then it might be a bug in POEdit. I noticed the same with Polish letters. Seems like they use some invalid encoding when reading files - the corrupted letters appear in a freshly opened file only (either original or saved via POEdit).

Comment: Yes, but its working when adding the POEdit Header data to the .po file, especially "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n" so POEdit recognize it as UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, the only situation when Poedit could possibly show “corrupted letters” is when the PO file in question incorrectly declares its encoding. See the spec at http://pology.nedohodnik.net/doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html